# CTreeCtrl with Explorer theme not DPI aware

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, treeview, dpi

I have an MFC app that is high dpi aware. The app displays a `CTreeCtrl`, which properly draws the expand/collapse (e.g. +/-) glyphs properly at different dpi settings. Here is a snippet at 200%.

[image]

In order to present a more modern appearance, I've set the tree control's theme to that of Windows Explorer by adding this to the tree control's `PreSubclassWindow` overide:

`SetWindowTheme(m_hWnd, L"Explorer", NULL);`

The tree control now draws the expand/collapse glyphs just like Windows Explorer, which is cool. But, the glyphs do not scale at high dpi settings. Here is another snippet at 200%

[image]

The theme part size at 200%, - `GetThemePartSize(td, NULL, TVP_GLYPH, GLPS_OPENED, NULL, TS_DRAW, &size)` - is 32 pixels. Clearly the Explorer themed glyphs are not growing in size as the dpi increases.

Has anyone else run int to this and, if so, did you find a resolution (other than owner/custom drawing the tree control?

Visual C++ 2015.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Like I said, my MFC app is already high dpi aware...

Comment: I don't understand the question, maybe post an image of what the problem looks like. Do you mean the arrow things look wrong?

Comment: Good idea - I've updated my initial post and add some more information - thanks!

Comment: To display those glyphs more smoothly in high DPI, there is an undocumented `0x1000` flag to fix the problem: `tree.SetExtendedStyle(0x1000, 0x1000)` or `SendMessage(hTree, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0x1000, 0x1000)` But I don't really have any idea...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani out of curiosity, what does this do at the DrawThemeBackground() level?

Comment: @andlabs It works fine with `OpenThemeData(0, L"Explorer::TreeView")`. Curiously, at 100% DPI, `DrawThemeBackground` doesn't scale the glyph. But at higher DPI it does scale based on the `RECT` parameter. But it's very possible that I got confused during login in/out and changing display settings.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the high dpi issue has nothing to do with setting the Windows theme. CTreeCtrl has a high dpi bug in that the expand/collapse (e.g. +/-) glyphs are not being properly scaled with or without setting a Windows them.

If you call `CTreeCtrl::GetItemPartRect` at different dpi scales, you will see the returned rectangle's height is scaled (due to the scaled font), but the width isn't. Thus, what I thought was an issue with the theme was only an illusion, because the themed expand/collapse glyphs have more transparent pixels.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time...